# Cannot mount via mount + fstab but can do via Other locations addition

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I have a question regarding to some strange behavior I find in mounting a shared windows drive.

Just to start, here I mounted the shared drive via manual addition (other locations):

[image]

As you can see, I mounted a drive "a" on ip address 10.90.1.52 and could access all the way to my desired location "R-N-D". and from there, I can also open terminal and play around there.

Now I wanted to do it via mount and fstab option and here is my fstab:
[image]

And when I tried to access "R-N-D" like I did above, I get a permission denied error:

[image]

So, I was wondering if sec option was the problem, and I tried the followings:

1. sec=ntlm,vers=3.0 => mount error(112): Host is down
2. sec=ntlmv2,vers=3.0 => can mount, but permission denied at child directory "R-N-D"
3. sec=ntlmv2,vers=2.0 => can mount, but permission denied at child directory "R-N-D"
4. sec=ntlm,vers=2.0 => mount error(2): No such file or directory

Any help on this? Btw, idk if this helps or not, even when i tried to mount a network drive via "Other Locations", I could not do it via hostname (smb://grexad01.grex.local/a/) so I had to use ip address (smb://10.90.1.52/a/).